# buildozer kivy app wont run on android with external kv file

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I'm newbie in coding with python/kivy. I have a problem building an android app via kivy buildozer.

First of all, if I build the app and I use kivy like this for example:

```
self.asdbut = Button(text="xxxxxx", font_size="70sp")
self.asdbut.bind(on_press=self.aaaaa)
self.add_widget(self.asdbut)
```

It works on both on pc and android phone.

But if I use kivy builder for external or inner script kv language the app runs on pc but not in android. So I guess I have to somehow add the kivy.lang.builder to the apk via buildozer init file. How can I achive that?

P.S. I've found a line in buildozer spec that say's :

```
# (list) Application requirements
requirements = kivy
```

So i've tried to include there builder but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Builder is class, not package. For loading either name it like your `App` class (`class My(App):` -> `my.kv`), or load with Builder this way:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<My>:
    property: value
''')
```

or

```
Builder.load_file(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'my.kv'))
```